# Azure Service Bus Queue takes a long time to send messages to the retriever

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, latency, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Currently, it takes a very long time for the messages to be retrieved. What's the expected latency of the Azure Service Bus standard plan? In my case, It can take even 20 seconds for the message to be retrieved from the service bus after sending them.

How this could be improved? Is it normal to have this latency?

Thanks

I could not find any resources on the expected latency of the service bus. They said performance it's not guaranteed, but what this really means...

Comment: are you using Azure Functions with the service bus trigger as the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer your question precisely, there *is* a way to answer it in general.

For reference:

> Service Bus offers various pricing tiers. It's recommended to pick the appropriate tier for your application requirements.
>
> **Standard tier** - Suited for developer/test environments or **low throughput** scenarios where the applications are not sensitive to throttling.
>
> **Premium tier** - Suited for production environments with **varied throughput** requirements where predictable latency and throughput are required. Additionally, Service Bus premium namespaces can be auto scaled and can be enabled to accommodate spikes in throughput.

From [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements)

This means that performance may vary depending on the selected service tier and the available load, and that Service Bus might throttle.

Like Thiago Custodio asked in [their comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75534529/azure-service-bus-queue-takes-a-long-time-to-send-messages-to-the-retriever/75534902#comment133266753_75534529) "are you using Azure Functions with a trigger?" Triggers might have a delay because of optimization and the fact that they are, in the end, polling.

**Asynchronous**
But most importantly: "Azure Service Bus is a fully managed enterprise message broker". And it is, in its very nature, an **asynchronous way of communication** between two (or more in case of topics) applications. It holds messages while it waits for earlier messages to be processed by the appropriate consumer(s).

If you're looking for a more direct way of communication between applications, have a look at directly calling APIs or leveraging the power of Azure Event Grid to build an [event driven architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/event-driven).